# Dynamically change searchable datatable column property

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have to change in one function, after the initialization of a datatable, `bSearchable` property of a column. I need first to enable and then disable it.

I found an example for visibility:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

Can something similar be used also in my case? Something like  `column.seachable`?

Comment: could you clarify what do you need to do ? how does it related to C# tag

Comment: Please be more specific. Why and when do you want to set searchable? It does not quite add up unless "something" needs to happen and *then* searchable should be disabled.

Comment: I need this because "global" search provided by datatable search typed value in input field in all existing columns. I want to restrict the search for one hidden column, but when i call a function made by me i need to perform a search on that column so i should activate this property and then deactivate it

Comment: i believe you have to re-initialize the table after calling your function

Comment: The function is called on a button click. I must re-initialize after every click?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but one that cost me several hours to research the answer to... mostly based on my lack of JS skill though.

The usecase was that I have a table with an ID column that is a `GUID`. This Id is seldom used uses a lot of space, so it's hidden and not searchable by default. But for internal users who might have access to logs or the database, we need to be able to search the ID column as well.

I added a checkbox for these users and it should change visibility and the searchable attribute of the ID column. 
My solution is based on [another question regarding searching on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579632/datatable-search-based-on-columns). But in this question, the search was only intended on one single column and not on all searchable columns as well (normal `DataTable.search()` API). Sadly, to change the `searchable` property, there seems to be no public API. If you change the `searchable` property, you have to invalidate the data in the table afterwards, otherwise the columns data will still be / not be present in the tables `aoFilterData`. This forces the table to reload the data from the datasource (in this case, the DOM).

I had a lot of problems with registering the eventhandlers at the right place. The filter field is not present at the first `draw` event of the table, so i had to register the handlers in the `init` event that is fired after the table is fully initialized.

```
var userTable;
var idSearchCbx;
var searchField;

$(document).ready(function () {
userTable = document.getElementById("table-users");
if (userTable) {
    userTable = $("#table-users").DataTable(
        {
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    //First column invisible and not searchable by default
                    "targets": [0], //first column = ID
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                }],
          //Other initialization options
    ); //Table creation
    userTable.on("init",
        function () {
            $("input[type='search']").on("change cut input keypress keyup paste search recheck",
                function () {
                    var searchValue = $(this).val();
                    userTable.search(searchValue).draw();
                    //width attribute is calculated and added to the table
                    //it loses 2 pixels everytime the checkbox is checked/
                    //unchecked somehow - so delete it
                    document.getElementById("table-users").removeAttribute("style");
                });

            idSearchCbx = $("#cbx-search-id");
            idSearchCbx.on("change",
                function () {
                    if (this.checked === true) {
                        //this makes the first column searchable, not official API
                        userTable.context[0].aoColumns[0].bSearchable = true;
                        //make it visible as well, official API
                        userTable.columns(0).visible(true);
                        //invalidates cached table data so that the column values are
                        //added to the filterdata
                        userTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
                    } else {
                        userTable.context[0].aoColumns[0].bSearchable = false;
                        userTable.columns(0).visible(false);
                        userTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
                    }
                    //trigger the normal search again so that the
                    //filter is / is not applied to the first column
                    $("input[type='search']").trigger("recheck");
                });
        }); //DT on init
    } //table present
});//document ready
```

I assume context is related to [`settings()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/settings()), so keep in mind that names in the context might change and this is most likely not version-stable even in minor releases. But I didn't find any other way. Hope it helps someone.